# PHP MySQL Multiple SQL Queries or JOIN for each query

Tags: php, mysql, function, join

If I have two tables with their respective columns:

```
=====================
product_categories
=====================
id | name
=====================

=======================
products
=======================
id | category_id | name
=======================
```

And I have the following PHP functions:

```
// Returns an array of all rows from the products
function getProducts() { ... } 

// returns the corresponding row to the given id of the product category
function getProductCategory($category_id) { ... }
```

Currently, I am displaying a list of all products in a table with the following headings:

- id
- Category
- Name

Where category is the name of the category corresponding to the `category_id` of the product.

Currently I am using a foreach loop to iterate through the product and calling the `getProductCategory(...)` function for each product:

```
<?php
...

$products = getProducts();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product_category = getProductCategory($product['category_id']);
    ...
}

...
?>
```

Which would be an extensive amount of queries to the database if there are lots of products with many repeated queries.

Would it be good practice if the `getProducts()` function include all it's category information using a `JOIN` in the `SQ`L statement?

Comment: I would suggest you to create another method. getProducts() looks like a simple CRUD operation, what you need it is more "customized". It is a good practice in terms of performace to create a custom query with the fields that you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `id`, `category_name` and `product_name` each time, you should make ONE method and avoid to make one `select`, then a `foreach` on each product and an other `select` to get all value.

So try something like this maybe :

```
function getProductsData() {

    $querie = 'SELECT 
                 p.id, p.name,
                 pc.name as Category
               FROM products as p
               LEFT JOIN product_categories as pc on pc.id = p.category_id
               ORDER BY p.name; -- optionnal
              ';

    // Get the data and return them
    // You should get an array with one row = 
    // id (of the product) / name (of the product) / Category (the name of the category)


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Join will be better. It will reduce the number of queries for fetching the category. Otherwise, you can do the separate query for getting the categories as below code, but I will suggest Join.

```
$products = getProducts();
$categoryIds = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $categoryIds[] = $product['category_id'];
    ...
}
$product_category = getProductCategory($categoryIds);
```

You have to modify the query in `getProductCategory()` and add `where in` condition for comparing category ID
In `getProductCategory()`, you can implode the category IDs, for adding it into the `where in` clause.